# Debian registers MS Sculpt mouse clicks erratically

Tags: mouse

I'm using MS Sculpt ergonomic kbd and mouse with Debian 11. The keyboard works AOK, the mouse not so much.

When I click something, the OS may not recognize it at all until at 4th or so click so choosing text or dragging a window is a drag. Other times it may recognize a double-click which means opening links twice etc.

Sometimes it even appears to register the click late; an example is me downvoting a posting and moving cursor up to close the tab, and next I notice I've actually *up*voted it :-P

I've noticed this problem only with this mouse and only with Linux, which to me suggests a driver issue, but I can't figure out how to start fixing that.

I've not discounted a HW issue either, but I don't have an active Windows installation anywhere to compare with, so have to start with SW.

Comment: In X11, sometimes `xinput` + `xinput list-props <someid>` gives out parameters to tinker on with `set-prop`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @A.B - investigating this, updating the question later on :-)